# DuckDB - What's the difference between .sql and .execute function?

Tags: python, duckdb

I am a newbie using DuckDb library in python and while going through [docs](http://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/guides/python/execute_sql) I stumbled upon 2 functions to execute sql instructions, namely execute() and sql().

What's the difference between the 2? I am really scratching my head with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `sql` and `execute` can be used to achieve the same results, they have slight differences which may impact which function you use.

The [sql](http://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/api/python/reference/index#duckdb.sql) function runs the query as-is. It will return a `DuckDBPyRelation` which allows "[constructing relationships](http://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/api/python/relational_api)".

> `duckdb.sql(query: str, alias: str = 'query_relation', connection: duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection = None) → duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation`
>
> Run a SQL query. If it is a SELECT statement, create a relation object from the given SQL query, otherwise run the query as-is.

The [execute](http://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/api/python/reference/index#duckdb.execute) function will also run queries, but can handle prepared statements that accepts parameters and returns the connection `DuckDBPyConnection` instead of a relationship.

> `duckdb.execute(query: str, parameters: object = None, multiple_parameter_sets: bool = False, connection: duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection = None) → duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection`
>
> Execute the given SQL query, optionally using prepared statements with parameters set